# IE8, Fancybox 2.0.2 Issues.

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I'm having problems with the latest version of fancybox 2.0.2 and am wondering if anyone can help me.

When closing an iFrame (YouTube) fancybox window on IE8 with the `closeEasing: easeInBack` option enabled, it doesn't close properly and the youtube video that is called up using fancybox gets blown up to fill the browser window. the only way to get back to the original page is to refresh the browser.

Here's the link: http://kamehamehapublishing.org/kumukahi/

I'm wondering what it could be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the last trailing comma since IE is expecting another API option. This may cause unexpected behavior in IE

```
closeEasing : 'easeInBack', //<-- no comma here
```